# See check mark again after dismissing a tableView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, checkmark

I have a table view with 3 sections (Services, Availability and Days) and multiple rows in each of them. I implemented a to see a check mark when select any row. Now, I want to see the selected rows again when displaying the table again after I dismiss it the first time. Like showing a history of the selected Items.

here is the code to show the check mark:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let indPath = indexPath
    let section = indPath.section
    switch section {
    case 0:
        updateCell(indPath, select: true)
    case 1:
        updateCell(indPath, select: true)
    case 2:
        updateCell(indPath, select: true)
    default:
        Void()
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let indPath = indexPath
    let section = indPath.section
    switch section {
    case 0:
        updateCell(indPath, select: false)
    case 1:
        updateCell(indPath, select: false)
    case 2:
        updateCell(indPath, select: false)
    default:
        Void()
     }
}

func updateCell(indexpath: NSIndexPath, select: Bool) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: indexpath.row, inSection: indexpath.section)) {
        if select{
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        }
        else {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }
    }//end if cell
```

Now here method where I get the the data from the selected rows:

```
func save(){
    if let indexPaths = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows{
        for indexPath in indexPaths{
            switch indexPath.section{
            case SectionIndex.Services.rawValue:
                switch indexPath.row{
                case ServicesIndex.Recieve.rawValue:
                    selectedServices.insert("RECEIVE")
                case ServicesIndex.Send.rawValue:
                    selectedServices.insert("SEND")
                default:
                    Void()
                }//end switch
            case SectionIndex.Availability.rawValue:
                switch indexPath.row{
                case AvailabiltiyIndex.Morning.rawValue:
                    selectedAvailabilities.append(6.0...9.0)
                case AvailabiltiyIndex.Regular.rawValue :
                    selectedAvailabilities.append(9.0...18.0)
                case AvailabiltiyIndex.Evening.rawValue:
                    selectedAvailabilities.append(18.0...21.0)
                default:
                    Void()
                }//end switch
            case SectionIndex.Days.rawValue:
                switch indexPath.row{
                case DaysIndex.Sunday.rawValue:
                    selectedDays.insert("Sunday")
                case DaysIndex.Monday.rawValue:
                    selectedDays.insert("Monday")
                case DaysIndex.Tuesday.rawValue:
                    selectedDays.insert("Tuesday")
                case DaysIndex.Wednesday.rawValue:
                    selectedDays.insert("Wednesday")
                case DaysIndex.Thursday.rawValue:
                    selectedDays.insert("Thursday")
                case DaysIndex.Friday.rawValue:
                    selectedDays.insert("Friday")
                case DaysIndex.Saturday.rawValue:
                    selectedDays.insert("Saturday")
                default:
                    Void()
                }//end switch
            default:
                Void()
            }//end switch
        }//end for
    }//end If
}//end save
```

Answer (score 0):

The selection state itself is lost after the table view is dismissed. Without taking care of it, it is only part of the state, which the views manage.

In your `save` method you are storing the "selection state". You have these `selectedServices`, `selectedAvailabilities` and `selectedDays` variables in which you store the selection state. If you still have these when showing the table view a second time, you could pull the selection state from them.

Likely you change the updateCell calls from this:

```
updateCell(indPath, select: false)
```

to this:

```
updateCell(indPath, select: selectionState(indPath))
```

And define a method like this: (note the `selectedServices.contains("RECEIVE")`)

```
func selectionState(indexpath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    let indPath = indexPath
    let section = indPath.section
    switch section {
    case 0:
        switch indexPath.row{
            case ServicesIndex.Recieve.rawValue:
                return selectedServices.contains("RECEIVE")
            ...
    case 1:
        updateCell(indPath, select: false)
    case 2:
        updateCell(indPath, select: false)
    default:
        Void()
    }
}
```

The `contains` method actually pulls out the selection state from the data model (which are these instances referenced by `selectedServices` etc.). If it is not possible to implement a `contains` method, you may have to create a data structure which only stores the selection state. You then read the selection state from that data structure and write the selection state to the data structure and to the `selectedServices` etc. instances.

Comment: Thx for you help. Actually after dismissing the table view any data selected is not stored. So basically what I have is a map view  and a filter button when I press the filter button navigate to the filter table view described above. What I need is after the user selecting the filter options he needs he should be able to see what he has selected when he goes back to the filter table view. I am new to swift and IOS. I am not sure how to save what the user has selected and how to retrieve it back. :)

Comment: You have a view controller (VC) which is used to bring up the filter table view (FVC). In VC keep the data structure which stores the selection state. Pass it on to FVC using `prepareForSegue` (google it). Then you can update the data structure while in the FVC and it will be there again when you open the FVC a second time. The data structure can be an array (sections) of dictionaries (rows) where the values are Bools (true/false = selected/not selected).

Answer (score 0):

I added a delegate method, In my filter I added the following:

```
protocol FilterSettingsDelegate:class{
    func filtercontrollerWillDissmiss(data: Set<NSIndexPath>)
}

class FilterTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    weak var delegate: FilterSettingsDelegate?
    var filterSettings : Set<NSIndexPath>? = []
...


 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.filterSettings!.insert(indexPath)

    let indPath = indexPath
    let section = indPath.section
    switch section {
    case 0:
        updateCell(indPath, select: true)
    ....

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if self.filterSettings != nil {
        self.filterSettings!.remove(indexPath)
    }
    let indPath = indexPath
    let section = indPath.section
    switch section {
    case 0:
    ....
```

In my Map view I added the following:

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, FilterSettingsDelegate {

var filterSettings : Set<NSIndexPath>?

....

//Delegate Method
 func filtercontrollerWillDissmiss(data: Set<NSIndexPath>) {
    self.filterSettings = data
}

//Then pass the data in the segue

case "FilterSegue" :
           let navController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
            if let controller = navController.topViewController as? FilterTableViewController{
                if self.filterSettings != nil{
                    controller.filterSettings = self.filterSettings
                }
                controller.delegate = self
            }
```